# Motorola-EMDK Barcode VB .NET Decoder Parameter Set

Tags: barcode, symbols, motorola, motorola-emdk

I am starting to developing an Application for WM 5.0 to read I2OF5 barcodes usinv VB.NET 2005.
The problem is that the barcodes have a length of 8 and I have to set the minlength parameter for the I2OF5 decoder.
I am able to do that in "Data Wedge", but I am not able to set in VB code??

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code:

```
    m_Reader.Actions.Enable()
    With m_Reader.Decoders
        .I2OF5.MinimumLength = 8
        .I2OF5.MaximumLength = 8
        .I2OF5.Enabled = True
    End With
```

Remember to set your min- and max-length to a very small variation because it is very dangerous to scan an I2of5, cause it could happen that only a part of the barcode is readed properly. E.g you receive "1234" instead of "1234567890". Hope this will help you.